# Why does Job compare his day with a weaver's shuttle?

Tags: job, misery

We see Job lamenting his miserable life in Job 7:6:

> My days are swifter than a weaver’s shuttle,and they come to an end without hope.

Generally, we feel that the day is longer when we confront boredom, misery and anxiety. Days look shorter when we are active and happy. Since Job is going through the sufferings of his life, he should feel the days dragging along. But, he calls them swifter than a weaver's  shuttle , which does not look like an appropriate metaphor. Is there a reason for the comparison ?

Answer (score 4):

This verse marks a transition from Job meditating on life's drudgery to its fleetingness. Once he lived a happy life, then he was struck with tragedy and his days dragged on in misery.

> I have been assigned months of futility,
> and troubled nights have been counted off for me. (vs. 3)

But now (in verse 6) he sees the coming upon him suddenly:

> My days are swifter than a weaver’s shuttle;
> they come to an end without hope. 7 Remember that my life is like the wind;
> my eye will not see happiness again. 8 The eye that now sees me shall no more behold me;
> when your eye is on me, I shall be gone. 9 As a cloud dissolves and vanishes,
> so whoever goes down to Sheol shall not come up.

Weaving is indeed a dull occupation. But in ancient times, before the invention of modern looms, a skilled weaver had to be deft in his use of the shuttle. The shuttle would move quickly, even though the cloth would emerge relatively slowly. So, in the context of the world that Job lived in, the analogy works.

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking in terms of time passing while in pain.  Job was looking at time as if his life was about to end. Note the double meaning of "end."  When you see the end of your life approaching, looking back at life, the time goes fast.

```
  My days fly faster than a weaver’s shuttle, 
  And come to their end without hope. 
                            (Job 7:6, JPS1985)
```

> I תִּקְוָה:  קוה, Bauer-Leander Heb. 495m: cstr. תִּקְוַת: cord, made out of a mass of threads, cf. גָּדִיל; Jos 2:18, 21: a)...

> II תִּקְוָה: קוה, Bauer-Leander Heb. 495m; MHeb. 1). end, outcome ...
> --
> Koehler, L., Baumgartner, W., Richardson, M. E. J., & Stamm, J. J. (1994–2000). In *The Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament* (electronic ed., p. 1781). E.J. Brill.

> 7:6. weaver’s shuttle. Some of the language needs clarification here. The word NIV translates “weaver’s shuttle” is elsewhere always rendered “loom.” The adjective they translate “swift” has the basic meaning of “light” or even “insubstantial.” Finally, the word translated “hope” [actually the word translated "end," see above] also means thread (e.g., Rahab’s scarlet thread in Josh 2:18). On the horizontal looms of the day, four stakes were driven into the ground in a rectangular pattern. The threads that would make up the warp of the fabric were tied at regular intervals to sticks on both ends, and the sticks were then used to stretch out the threads between the stakes. When the ends of each stick were braced behind the stakes, the threads would be stretched horizontal to the ground, taut for weaving. A shuttle would then be tied to the thread that was to be woven in as the woof of the fabric, with a bar being used to separate alternating threads of the warp to allow the shuttle with the woof thread to pass through. Once the woof thread was in place, the pin would be used to tighten that row against the previous rows. When the fabric was complete, the warp threads would be cut from the loom, leaving only remnants of threads tied to sticks. The following translation picks up the imagery: “My days are more insubstantial than a loom in that they come to an end with no hope/thread.”
> --
> Matthews, V. H., Chavalas, M. W., & Walton, J. H. (2000). *The IVP Bible background commentary: Old Testament* (electronic ed., Job 7:6). InterVarsity Press.

> 7:6–7. Job saw his life on earth as lasting for a brief time and then gone forever. My days are swifter than a weaver’s shuttle, tossed back and forth, moving rapidly with the thread running out.
> --
> Lawson, S. J. (2005). *Job* (M. Anders, Ed.; pp. 68–69). B&H Publishing Group.

Think of the song in *Fiddler on the Roof*, "Sun Rise, Sun Set."